# How to create a fixed menu (links come from right to left) - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a fixed menu. The menu has three areas. When hover on an area, a link will stretch (from left to right). And the three links are different (distances).
Here is my demo of the menu:
    
[image]
    
I spent all day to code but It doesn't work. I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: do you want ti to stretch from left to right or right to left because you are being a bit controversial.

Comment: You are required to supply a minimal example of your markup that shows the problem here, not some third-party site that can change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: @ZombieChowder: I need my links stretch from right to left.

Comment: Do you want the links to be the same width or not? It is not entirely clear from your question.

Comment: @FilipHedman: I need the links have different widths. Sorry this inconvenience.

Comment: Okay, then you have accepted the wrong answer, because the links are all 200px in that case. See my answer for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these CSS properties:

```
.cs-menu .item {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap; // Prevent word break
    overflow: hidden; // Hidden content when container too small
    padding-left: 40px; // Push the text to the right to hide it when folded
    box-sizing: border-box; // don't take padding into account to calculate width
}
```

```css
.cs-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right: 10%;
}

.cs-menu .item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.cs-menu .temp {
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
}

.cs-menu .item:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
  <div class="item">Link-one</div>
  <div class="item">Link-two two</div>
  <div class="item">Link-three three three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But there is a problem. How can I remove padding-left: 40px when I left an area?
I add this code but It works not well: 
    .cs-menu .item:hover {
      width: 200px;
      padding-left: 0;
    }

Comment: Why do you need to remove padding ? You want the beginning of the inside text to show when folded ?

Answer (score 1):

To give each item a different length, you have to create three different classes or ID's. (both will do the job)

```
<div class="cs-menu">
        <div class="item item1">Link-one</div>
        <div class="item item2">Link-two two</div>
        <div class="item item3">Link-three three three</div>
```

```
.cs-menu .item1:hover {
width: 100px;
}
.cs-menu .item2:hover {
width: 150px;
}
.cs-menu .item3:hover {
width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the separate items based using percent instead of a fixed width, like this:

```css
.cs-menu {
 position: fixed;
 top: 35%;
 right:10%;
}

.cs-menu .item {
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 40px;
        padding-left: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #ccc;
        transition: width 1s;
        margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.cs-menu .item:hover {
        width: calc(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
 <div class="item">Link-one</div>
    <div class="item">Link-two two</div>
   <div class="item">Link-three three three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc to and width 100% to make the width accoeding to the string size and add to it 10px to have some space from the border

```
.cs-menu .item:hover {
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  float:right;
}
```

```css
.cs-menu {
 position: fixed;
 top: 35%;
 right:10%;
}

.cs-menu .item {
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 40px;
 background: #ccc;
  transition: width 1s;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.cs-menu .temp {
  border: 1px solid red;
 width: 40px;
 background: green;
}

.cs-menu .item:hover {
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
   <div class="item">Link-one</div>
   <div class="item">Link-two two</div>
   <div class="item">Link-three three three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cs-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right: 10%;
}
.cs-menu .item {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  max-height: 70px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: width 1s;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cs-menu .temp {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  background: green;
}
.cs-menu .item:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
  <div class="item">Link-one</div>
  <div class="item">Link-two two</div>
  <div class="item">Link-three three three</div>
</div>
```